# Anomaly detection within a dataset in R

Tags: r, prediction, anomaly-detection

I would like to detect patterns within a weather dataset of around 10'000 data points. I have around 40 possible predictors (temperature, humidity etc.) which may explain good or bad weather the next day (dependent variable). Normally, I would apply classical machine learning methods like Random Forest to build and test models for classifying the whole dataset and find reliable predictors to forecast the next day's weather.

My task though is different. I want to find predictors and their parameters which "guarantee" me good or bad weather in a subset of the overall data. I am not interested in describing the whole dataset but finding the pattern of predictors (and their parameters) that give me good or bad weather indications. So I am trying to find, for example, 100 datapoints with 100% good weather if certain predictors are set to certain levels. I am not interested in the other 9'900 datapoints.

It is kind of the task of trying all combinations and calibrations of the predictors to find a subset of the overall data points which can be predicted with very high accuracy.

How would you do this systematically?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about the appropriate use of various statistical methods, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] or [datasciense.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This seems to be a statistical methods problem. Also, there is no guarantee that any set of your variables will construct an "only contains good weather" outcome.